# importing binary strings using json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I like to import regular expressions using binary strings like

```
    ReplaceChars = (
    ('UTF8 HYPHEN '   , b'\xe2\x80\x90', b'\x2d'),
    ('UTF8 EN DASH'   , b'\xe2\x80\x93', b'\x2d'),
    ('UTF8 EM DASH'   , b'\xe2\x80\x94', b'\x2d'),
  )
```

Currently this is hardcoded in my python source, but I like to to have it in a different file to be more flexible.

I normally use json.load(jsonfile) to do this, but it seems that json is not working with the binary strings...

I tried to dump ReplaceChars into a json file:

```
with open('result.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(ReplaceChars, f)
```

but it causes the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
[...]
    TypeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable
```

Is there a workaround in json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be better to store the characters and encode to bytes in your application as needed (rather than hand-hard-coding the UTF-8 representation)

for example, considering the `UTF8 HYPHEN`:

```
>>> '\u2010'
'‐'
>>> '\u2010'.encode()
b'\xe2\x80\x90'
>>> '-'.encode()
b'-'
>>> {'UTF8 HYPHEN': ['\u2010', '-']}
{'UTF8 HYPHEN': ['‐', '-']}
>>> print(json.dumps({'UTF8 HYPHEN': ['\u2010', '-']}))
{"UTF8 HYPHEN": ["\u2010", "-"]}
>>> json.loads('{"UTF8 HYPHEN": ["\\u2010", "-"]}')['UTF8 HYPHEN'][0].encode()
b'\xe2\x80\x90'
```

Comment: I have also CP1252 EN DASH as 'b/x96'... how to handle them?

Comment: `.encode('cp1252')` will take a unicode string and give you the bytes you need

Answer (score 1):

You can use e.g. Base64 encoding to represent your binary data as strings. See here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a JSON file, you can use the pickle file to store binary strings data.

```
import pickle
from ast import literal_eval as make_tuple
ReplaceChars = (
    ('UTF8 HYPHEN '   , b'\xe2\x80\x90', b'\x2d'),
    ('UTF8 EN DASH'   , b'\xe2\x80\x93', b'\x2d'),
    ('UTF8 EM DASH'   , b'\xe2\x80\x94', b'\x2d'),
  )

with open('result.pkl', 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(ReplaceChars, file)

with open('result.pkl', 'rb') as file:
    Result_ReplaceChars = pickle.load(file)

print(Result_ReplaceChars)
```

Comment: This results in a binary file... since I need to have some human readable file for better handling this is not running for me